# After Insert Trigger....Looping

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, triggers

What would the processing load concern be if I had an "After Insert" trigger created on a table and in that trigger I performed a While loop to iterate through "potentially" multiple rows?

End result is I will 99.999% of the time have only 1 row, but as the future is unpredictable i also want to be able to handle multiple rows being inserted.

Trigger Model:
1) Insert information into the table
2) Create views specific to the client, via stored procedures (if possible)

What Say You? :)

Haven't fully developed but this is the design i am looking for, may not be structurally sound but should get the point acrossed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.New_Client_Setup 
   ON  dbo.client 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Fill Temp Table
     select * into #clients
     from inserted

     --Iterate through Temp Table
     While (select count(*) from #clients) <> 0 BEGIN
         declare @id int, @clnt nvarchar(10)

         select top(1)
            @id = id
            , @clnt = short
         order by id desc

         Execute dbo.sp_Create_View_Client ( @id, @clnt )

         -- Drop used ID
         delete from #clients
         where id = @id
     END

     Drop table #clients
END
GO
```

Again, observe the design of the trigger not necessarily the syntactic sugar

Comment: A `WHILE` loop in a trigger is a pretty terrible idea, and a code smell for your DB design.  If your design **REQUIRES** this, then something somewhere went terribly wrong.

Comment: yeah that is what i am aware of but seems to be the only solution to handling the possibility of multiple rows being inserted.  As i am working on SQL 2005 Std.

Comment: If you post your code then maybe someone will be able to show you a different possibility.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of trigger is way off but I assumed the trigger was fired for each row even if the insert statement inserted multiple rows.  How does SQL 2005 Std behave?

Comment: @BalamBalam - in SQL Server, a trigger fires once for each atomic operation (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE) - the resultset of affected rows are stored in special `deleted` and `inserted` tables

Comment: You can `Join` the `inserted`-table instead of creating a new temp table. That should work in SQL 2005 Std. without a problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Tim - I dont quite understand what Join'ing the `inserted` will provide when doing iterations?

Comment: Your method is the only way I can think of to do it. Although I'd probably use a table variable rather than a temp table for scoping reasons.

Comment: @JNappi - Thanks, i know its not the pretiest code, and im up for any advise on making it cleaner and more stable (time to process).  But with the current Version limitation, it seems about the only method available.  I dont really like using Cursor'y methods but if its necessary i will.

Comment: @All - Any other advise or suggestions before i nail this one to the wall and use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Design wise, reading the comments, I think you do not neccesarily need to do this in triggers. I would say you should do it as part of your insert statement in transactions - i.e. do the insert, and then do the loop that you want to do (whatever that does - execute dbo.sp_Create_View_Client)...

The second thing I would mention is what exactly is dbo.sp_Create_View_Client doing - is it a must-dependent on the insert? Meaning, what happens if the insert works fine, and the trigger fails? I would maybe do the whole insert and execute of the SP all in one transaction, so as to preserve data integrity.

Comment: It will create the Views that would be available for the new client, since i am also setting up the database to be partitioned.  I already have the Partition Function and Scheme drawn out now i am trying to setup the views as such.  The only thing that differs between the view structure between the clients is their unique ID.

Comment: So, then why don't you do this during/after the insert itself, and not on the trigger?

Comment: For the most part, the insert will occur at the Website and i want to include the necessary structure redesign.  Main point is i am implementing a Partition on the Tables based on the client ID and as such, After Insert is the closest opportune time to effect anything that is solely based on the client, and their unique ID.